# Is there a way to blacklist some audio devices?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, thinkpad

Ubuntu 20.04.2, Thinkpad

After connection to dock, there appears new devices, such as:

- Digital output (S/PDIF) - ThinkPad Dock USB Audio
- Analog output - ThinkPad Dock USB Audio
- Digital Input (S/PDIF) - ThinkPad Dock USB Audio

[image: S/PDIF audio]
[image: Analog audio]

The main problem - default input and output device switches to this devices and does not switches to headphones, when they connected.

It there a way to make system ignore them? (not to show and not to use)

Comment: if they use an own specific driver that no other device uses you could blacklist that specific driver / module. use `lspci -knn` and check which driver is in use and blacklist that one in `/etc/modprobe.d/`. Beforehand you can try `modprobe` to revoke the module manually `modprobe -r themodule` and if you dont like the result bring it back with `modprobe themodule`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out, that if in `pavucontrol` I mark some devices as off, on connection to dock, current audio device not switches to it:

[image]

So, it fully solved my problem

Comment: does not persist on reboot ...

Comment: @julienfr112 It seems to survive reboot in my case (Ubuntu 22.04).