# Automatically switch audio output (and ignore some outputs)

Tags: 20.04, sound

Not sure whether this will be a duplicate question since some aspects of it are case-specific.

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 on my HP laptop. When I plug my earplugs in and out the output sound does not get switched automatically every time (some times it does, but most of the time I have to do it manually). When I open sound settings there is a total of 4 output devices:

- *Speakers - Built-in Audio* or *Headphones* depending on whether my earplugs are plugged in
- *HDMI / Display Port - Built-in Audio* - which corresponds to my monitor's speakers
- *Headphones - USB Audio* - I assume the 3.5mm jack on my USB C docking station
- *Digital Output (S/PDIF) - USB Audio* - I have no idea

The only two options I'm ever interested in using both correspond to the first output device, that is:

- when my earplugs are plugged in I want *Headphones - Built-in Audio*
- when they aren't plugged in I want *Speakers - Build-in Audio*

It seems to me that the automatic choice of those four options is mostly random when I plug/unplug my earplugs.

Is there a way to ensure that the last 3 options never get selected, and to only ever keep it at either *Headphones - Built-in Audio* or *Speakers - Build-in Audio* depending on whether my earplugs are plugged in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to blacklist some audio devices?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1346214/250300)

Comment: UPDATE: Never solved this, just one of those linux things :D This, and many other inconveniences, made me switch back to Windows + WSL on personal computers.